# GET web api method from a Wordpress PHP script

Tags: plugins, php, wp-remote-get, web-services

I'm working on relaying the information that the formcraft plugin dumps into a GET web api method. The information from the formcraft plugin is saved into the variable **$_REQUEST**.

[Formcraft calls the handler.php](http://formcraft-wp.com/help/send-data-to-custom-url/) when submitting a form and this is the code (within the handler.php) I'm currently working with:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://x.x.x.x/Get_VacationRequest/';  
    $jsonData = json_encode($_REQUEST);     

    $response = wp_remote_get( $url, $jsonData );
?>
```

I'm debugging my WEB APIs and waiting for a request but so far nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what your code above is doing in relationship to the "formcraft" post. Is this the code inside the handler file (as in the example that you linked above)? "I am not getting a hit" - as in the form is not actually posting to your handler? Which form method are you using - POST or GET? Can you `var_dump` the results of $_POST and $_GET instead of $_REQUEST? Are you trying to re-post those values to the remote url ('Get_VacationRequest') and not getting a response? Can you `var_dump` the response from `wp_remote_get`?

Comment: Is this an API or Proxy? What are you passing in your $_GET request and what is the expected response? The second arg of wp_remote_get has specific values that it's expecting. Do you want to sanitize user data before passing along?

Comment: @jgraup Its a API that I have published on an external IP patching into my internal network either requesting information or posting a new Vacation Request. I'm okay with sending the whole json object and deserializing it on the Web API side. I'm expecting to consume the API and pass the parameter (jsonData).

Comment: @guiniveretoo I'm sorry but I'm a little bit new (like about a day new lol) with WordPress. I'm debugging on a live site and having a little bit of trouble trying to set that up. I will look into doing a var_dump. I do have this to say if I add any code after the WP_REMOTE_GET it does not execute the code after so I'm assuming that its failing.

Comment: Yeah, generally everything failing after a method call means something threw an uncaught exception; dig up the log files (google for your OS and use find, grep, or locate to figure out where they are) to track down the error message. Do you have a staging or dev environment to debug with? It'd be easier if you could make WP_DEBUG = true and start seeing the error messages right on the screen.

Comment: Send your request to https://requestb.in to see what you're passing

Answer (score 0):

wp_remote_get was causing the issue and switch over to a curl solution.

The code below replaced my old solution:

```
$serverIP = 'x.x.x.x';
$serviceAPI = '/Get_VacationRequest';

$jsonData = urlencode(json_encode($_REQUEST));

// Set up the server information where we will consume the API
$url = 'http://' . $serverIP . $serviceAPI . '?name=' . $jsonData;  

// Start the curl session
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```